# Printing a Linked List in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment where I need to create a Linked List given a template. However, up until this point, I've been stumped on how to print out the linked list. Can anyone figure out what am I doing wrong?

*Edit:*
Sorry, I should point out that I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error on line 27 of NumberList when I compile.

error when I compile.

**NumberList.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberList {

  private Node head;

  public NumberList() {
  }
  public void insertAtHead(int x) {
      Node newNode = new Node(x);

      if (head == null)
          head = newNode;
      else {
          newNode.setNext(head);
          head = newNode;
      }
  }
  public void insertAtTail(int x) {
  }
  public void insertInOrder(int x) {
  }
  public String toString() {
      Node tmp = head;

      String result = "";
      while (tmp.getNext() != null) {
          result += tmp.toString() + " ";
      }

      return result;
  }
  //---------------------

  // test methods

  //---------------------

  public static void testInsertAtHead() {

        Random r = new Random();
        int n = 20;
        int range = 1000;

        NumberList list = new NumberList();

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
              int x = r.nextInt(range);
              list.insertAtHead(x);
              System.out.println("" + x + ": " + list);
        }
  }

  public static void testInsertAtTail() {

        Random r = new Random();
        int n = 20;
        int range = 1000;

        NumberList list = new NumberList();

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
              int x = r.nextInt(range);
              list.insertAtTail(x);
              System.out.println("" + x + ": " + list);
        }
  }

  public static void testInsertInOrder() {

      Random r = new Random();
        int n = 20;
        int range = 1000;

        NumberList list = new NumberList();

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
              int x = r.nextInt(range);
              list.insertInOrder(x);
              System.out.println("" + x + ": " + list);
        }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        //testInsertAtHead();
        //testInsertAtTail();
        testInsertInOrder();
  }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
class Node {

  private int number;
  private Node next;

  public Node(int n) {
     this.number = n;
     this.next = null;
  }
  public Node getNext() {
      return next;
  }
  public int getNumber() {
      return number;
  }
  public void setNext(Node n) {
      if (n == null)
          return;

      n.setNext(next);
      next = n;
  }
  public String toString() {
      return number + "";
  }

}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
while (tmp.getNext() != null) {
    result += tmp.toString() + " ";
}
```

You are not advancing to the next link in your list at all. You should consider performing
 `tmp = tmp.getNext()`. But before doing so make sure your `while` condition is
`while (tmp != null)` to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

And the `NullPointerException` you are getting in *line 27* (which we can't know where it is) is probably because `head` isn't initialized since you call `insertInOrder` before `insertAtHead`, which is the only place where `head` is initialized in your program.

Comment: I've changed it to:
`while (tmp != null) {
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
        result += tmp.toString() + " ";
       }`

but it's printing out whitespace

Comment: No, the `tmp = tmp.getNext();` comes *after* the `result += tmp.toString() + " "; `

Comment: Ahh, that's right. Still getting whitespace for some reason though.

Comment: @JasonKhalili I sincerely hope you used a debugger by now and found out your problem. The answer I gave you is complete and covers and *potential* errors your code have. Going further than that is just pure debugging which should take no more than 5-10 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

You're calling insertAtTail and insertInOrder methods, but they are empty. As well as your NumberList constructor.